# issue with abstract classes and netbeans

Tags: java, abstract-class

I am using Java Beans for making a simple program using an abstract class. The rough sketch of my form is:

Payment to do(label)

this label is in a JFrame.

Now I have an abstract class called payment which has the following form:

```
public abstract class Payment {
    private double amount;
    Payment(){
        amount=1200.56;
    }
    public double getAmount(){
        return amount;
    }
    public abstract boolean verified();
}
```

So what I want is that when the program starts running the value of amount to be printed in the label that is in the JFrame. I have done this:

```
public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        Payment pay=new Payment();
        jLabel1.setText(Double.toString(pay.getAmount()));
    }
```

The error message that I got is that I cannot instantiate an abstract class. Theoretically I have read that is not possible, but using anonymous abstract classes. Is there another way that I can solve my problem? I mean to put in the label the amount to be paid?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to instantiate an abstract class? What should a call of `verified()` do in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a concrete Payment class.

Here is an example of how to use an anonymous concrete Payment class:

```
 Payment pay=new Payment() { public boolean verified() { return false; } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need such a class to be abstract exactly? You can create a subclass of the class and set the values there but I'm unsure what the purpose of this example is :s

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create an instance of `abstract` class.

Whatever you want to do, you can do it by extending your `abstract` class.